# Как сделать чтобы размер <figure> автоматически подстраивался под размер картинки?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать чтобы размер `<figure>` автоматически подстраивался под размер картинки, которая внутри него находится?

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://dev.finmaxbo.com/uploads/posts/2017-09/1505212460_14f029400dd0c8657ccc0288bef49f3a.jpg">
    <figcaption>figure caption test </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `width:min-content;`

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://dev.finmaxbo.com/uploads/posts/2017-09/1505212460_14f029400dd0c8657ccc0288bef49f3a.jpg">
  <figcaption>figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: спасибо! то, что нужно

Comment: нажмите на галочку в левом вехнем углу ответа если посчитали ответ верным.

Answer (score 1):

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://dev.finmaxbo.com/uploads/posts/2017-09/1505212460_14f029400dd0c8657ccc0288bef49f3a.jpg">
  <figcaption>figure caption test </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: border, для наглядности

Comment: тут штука в том, что если добавляю больше текста в описание, то оно отталкивает родительский див
<figure>
  <img src="https://dev.finmaxbo.com/uploads/posts/2017-09/1505212460_14f029400dd0c8657ccc0288bef49f3a.jpg">
  <figcaption>figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test figure caption test</figcaption>
</figure>

Comment: вы хотите, что бы и figcaption тоже автоматом выравнивался под img?

Comment: да, такая задумка

Comment: чего-то я не соображу как сделать...  добавьте больше информации. в чем содержитмся figure?

Comment: решил, повесил figcaption на абсолют относительно figure

#dle-content figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
figcaption {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

Comment: вы же просили исходя из данной ситуации???  )))  ну и отлично... выложите пример, любопытно посмотреть, у меня не получилось и совсем другая картина...